# How can I change size of pictures in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I try to develop website for my portfolio. I want to do something like that :
[image]

But I've some problem with the 3 icons for Twitter/Instagram and Deviantart. To put the icons like that, I use the flexbox in html. Currently, I've that :

```css
#conteneur {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteneur">
  <div class="element1">
    <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/vbxh.png">
  </div>
  <div class="element2">
    <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/4gl0.png">
  </div>
  <div class="element3">
    <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/dbtc.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Test with CodePen here : https://codepen.io/lucbenedet/pen/yLbPMgK

But as you can see, the pictures are too large and when I try to put the pictures to a size of 35px like that :

```
#conteneur
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    width: 35px;

}
```

or

```
.element1
{
    width: 35px;
}
```

The resize doesn't works...

Someone to show how to do that ?

Comment: Hello, indeed it works but the space between each pictures has decreased, seems like that the `justify-content: space-between` doesn't work anymore ?

Comment: Maybe read up a little more about the different values for `justify-content` and familiarize yourself with CSS flexbox in general? `space-between` will spread all remaining space evenly between the flex children: if your parent element is very wide, then of course they will be spread far apart. Try `justify-content: center`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your CSS with following code.

```css
#conteneur {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#conteneur div img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteneur">
  <div class="element1">
    <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/vbxh.png">
  </div>
  <div class="element2">
    <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/4gl0.png">
  </div>
  <div class="element3">
    <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/dbtc.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can have some space between icons when you maximize the width of the container

Answer (score 1):

you can reset width on the flex-container to max-content (3 icones shouldnot overflow) and use gap to set a distance in between them.

You could use em for the gap and icon's width to have a coherent render.

Possible example:

```css
#conteneur {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 1.6em;
}

#conteneur div img {
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteneur">
  <div class="element1">
    <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/vbxh.png">
  </div>
  <div class="element2">
    <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/19/51/4gl0.png">
  </div>
  <div class="element3">
    <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/29/dbtc.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

possible example from your codepen https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBmVjBV